# Returning a promise in async function - What is a more elegant / better practice solution?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am fairly new to async/await and while the following code seems to be working just fine, I have a sense that there must be a much more elegant / best practice way to write this function:

```
    /**
     * 
     * @param {string} email user email address
     * @description validates project exists and project owner is userId.
     * @returns {Promise} resolves userId if found otherwise null
     */
    async getUserFirstAndLastName (userId) {
        var userName;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var params = {
                UserPoolId: process.env.userPoolId, /* required */
                AttributesToGet: [
                'given_name',
                'family_name'
                /* more items */
                ],
                Filter: `sub = \"${userId}\"`
            };
            console.log("UserUtils DDB Get User First and Last Name:" + JSON.stringify(params, null,'  '));
            cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
                if(err){ // an error occurred
                    console.log(err, err.stack);
                    reject(err); // throw error
                }
                else { // successful response
                    console.log("Data: " + JSON.stringify(data, null,'  '));
                    if(data.Users.length){
                        userName = data.Users[0].Attributes[0].Value + " "; // First Name
                        userName += data.Users[0].Attributes[1].Value; // Last Name
                        resolve(userName); //return
                    }
                    else {
                        resolve(null); // no user found that matches email
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Seeking guidance...

Comment: Looks just fine to me (though no need for the function to be `async`, and there are a couple tiny improvements to be made, but the function overall is the right way to transform a callback into a Promise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with your code really seems to be around this line:

```
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
    ...
});
```

This is the old [callback style way of handling asynchronous code](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-from-callbacks-to-async-await-1cc090ddad99).

The real way you want to write your code, is for instead of that `listUsers` function be accepting a callback, it returns a promise. Then you could write your code this way:

```
async getUserFirstAndLastName (userId) {
        const params = {
            UserPoolId: process.env.userPoolId, /* required */
            AttributesToGet: [
            'given_name',
            'family_name'
            /* more items */
            ],
            Filter: `sub = \"${userId}\"`
        };

        try {
            const data = await cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params);
            if(data.Users.length){
                let userName = data.Users[0].Attributes[0].Value + " "; // First Name
                userName += data.Users[0].Attributes[1].Value; // Last Name
                return userName; 
            }
            else {
                return null; // no user found that matches email
            }
        }catch(err) {
            throw err; 
        });
    });
}
```

Assuming that you can't just straight rewrite that `listUsers` function, you could write a function that converts it to a function that returns a promise, like this:

```
function convertCallbackFnToAsyncFn(fn) {
    //Note that we are returning a function
    return (...args) => new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        fn(...args, (err, data) => {
             if (err) {
                reject(err); 
             }
             else {
               resolve(data); 
             }
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

And fitting this in with the solution above:

```
        try {
            //I'm just naming it newFunction here to be really clear about what we're doing
            const newFunction = convertCallbackFnToAsyncFn(cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers);
            const data = await newFunction(params);
            ....
```

Note that I'm using some ES6 spread/rest and fat arrow syntax in my answer.

Comment: The `convertCallbackFnToAsyncFn()` is called [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

Comment: @dwjohnston This was what I was looking for!  Beautiful!  Thanks!!